# Multi column join in pandas from groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe and a small dataframe that I would like to join together.  The small dataframe holds the maximum weekly value corresponding to the range of values in the larger dataframe by group. I want to join the maximum value per week per group to the large frame.

large frame:

```
L
datetime     group    value
2014-05-07   A        3 
2014-05-07   B        3 
2014-05-14   A        4 
2014-05-14   B        2 
2014-05-15   A        6 
2014-05-15   B        4 
2014-05-16   A        7 
2014-05-16   B        10
```

small frame:

```
S
weeknumber   group    maxval
1            A        3
1            B        3
2            A        7
2            B        10
```

Note these are hypothetical week values, the actual values will correspond to the week number in the year, out of 52.

To calculate the small frame, we can set an index on our datetime:

```
import pandas as pd
L.index = pd.to_datetime(L.datetime)
```

We can group by groups and week like so:

```
week = L.groupby([(lambda x : x.week),'group'], as_index=False)
```

Calculating the weekly max is simple:

```
weekmax = week.value.max()
```

This returns the small frame and is where I get stuck.  I have tried merging the dataframes and performing joins but can't get it to work.

EDIT:
This is what I want the final frame to look like after the join:

```
datetime     group    value    maxval
2014-05-07   A        3        3
2014-05-07   B        3        3
2014-05-14   A        4        7
2014-05-14   B        2        10
2014-05-15   A        6        7
2014-05-15   B        4        10
2014-05-16   A        7        7
2014-05-16   B        10       10
```

Comment: I might not have understood you question clearly. It appears that after joining you are left with the smaller frame. You can avoid that by using `how='left'` or `how='right'` as a join parameter. By default, join uses `how='inner'`, which leaves you with only the intersection of the merged values.

Comment: edited to show desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `transform` which will return a like-indexed version of the aggregation.  So you can assign directly back to the larger frame, like this:

```
In [189]: L['maxval'] = week['value'].transform('max')

In [190]: L
Out[190]: 
              datetime group  value  maxval
datetime                                   
2014-05-07  2014-05-07     A      3       3
2014-05-07  2014-05-07     B      3       3
2014-05-14  2014-05-14     A      4       7
2014-05-14  2014-05-14     B      2      10
2014-05-15  2014-05-15     A      6       7
2014-05-15  2014-05-15     B      4      10
2014-05-16  2014-05-16     A      7       7
2014-05-16  2014-05-16     B     10      10
```

Comment: This gives NaN's when applied to my real dataset, perhaps because my time interval includes hh:mm:ss?

Comment: @camdenl - That shouldn't be an issue, are you sure `L` and `week` are referencing the same DataFrame?  Please post a copy-pasteable version of the error if you're still having troubles.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a typo, now I am getting: 'incompatible index of inserted column with frame index'

Comment: @camdenl - Please edit your question to show a reproducible example of how you're getting that error.

Comment: For some reason I needed to call sort_index on each data frame and then it worked fine, thank you for your help.