# Calculated column from datetime range and group in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to calculate the max value per week per group and to create a new column with these values in pandas.  I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572826/multi-column-join-in-pandas-from-groupby) a similar question that did not solve my problem, so I restructured the question.

Consider a dataframe with timestamp, group and value columns:

```
datetime     group    value
2014-05-07   A        3 
2014-05-07   B        4 
2014-05-14   A        4 
2014-05-14   B        2 
2014-05-15   A        6 
2014-05-15   B        4 
2014-05-16   A        7 
2014-05-16   B        10
```

I want to create a new column with the maximum value per week by group:

```
datetime     group    value    maxval
2014-05-07   A        3        3
2014-05-07   B        4        4
2014-05-14   A        4        7
2014-05-14   B        2        10
2014-05-15   A        6        7
2014-05-15   B        4        10
2014-05-16   A        7        7
2014-05-16   B        10       10
```

In the linked question, the solution presented was to transform a groupby clause and then attach it to the dataframe, however this is creating ordering errors in the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `transform` groups indexed on both `group` and the week simultaneously:

```
>>> week = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.datetime).week
>>> df["maxval"] = df.groupby(['group', week])["value"].transform('max')
>>> df
     datetime group  value  maxval
0  2014-05-07     A      3       3
1  2014-05-07     B      4       4
2  2014-05-14     A      4       7
3  2014-05-14     B      2      10
4  2014-05-15     A      6       7
5  2014-05-15     B      4      10
6  2014-05-16     A      7       7
7  2014-05-16     B     10      10
```

Note that if you have multiple years this will combine the second week (e.g.) of each year into the same group.

Sometimes people want that, but if you don't, you could add the year to the grouped quantities in the same way.

---

If you want instead a rolling maximum, you can use (appropriately enough) `rolling_max`.  You can either resample yourself or get `rolling_max` to do it, something like

```
def rolling_max_week(x):
    rolled = pd.rolling_max(x, 7, min_periods=1, center=True, freq='d')
    match_x = rolled.loc[x.index]
    return match_x

df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df = df.set_index("datetime")
df["rolling_max"] = df.groupby("group")["value"].transform(rolling_max_week)
df["bin_max"] = df.groupby(["group", df.index.week])["value"].transform(max)
```

Now as it happens, these two produce exactly the same output on your sample:

```
>>> df
           group  value  rolling_max  bin_max
datetime                                     
2014-05-07     A      3            3        3
2014-05-07     B      4            4        4
2014-05-14     A      4            7        7
2014-05-14     B      2           10       10
2014-05-15     A      6            7        7
2014-05-15     B      4           10       10
2014-05-16     A      7            7        7
2014-05-16     B     10           10       10
```

but that won't be true in general.  You'll want to read the documentation for `rolling_max` and play around with some test cases to be sure that I'm interpreting what you want correctly.

Comment: What if I want to choose a week from each day, for instance use the day as the middle of the week and do three days before and three days after?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Are you trying (1) to shift the definition of a week by a few days, or (2) do you want a rolling window, so that each day has a different week we're taking the maximum over?

Comment: A moving window, each day with a different week, using that day as a median.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of NaN's in my real dataset, I think because my timestamp index includes hour, minutes, seconds.